# Keyframed animation into path animation

Tags: animation, game-engine, objects, keyframes, path

I have got an animated object that is an opening door. I keyframed the movements; not rig there. Now I want to get rid of the keyframes and create an animation path that does just the same but without the keyframes. Is that even possible? I am not that skilled with animation nor do I know what is possible and what not. Hope someone can clearify this for me. I want to use this created path for the BGE and apply it (on the relative movement from the local space on) to more doors later on, so that I can use it in a python command later on (to toggle the door opening). 
I know this might be an advanced question, but I thought why not ask. If it's too demanding I will ask out of this forum, though, so that I don't bother anyone with almost doing a tutorial for this.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your demand sounds a bit strange considering the fact the BGE does not support paths.

You already have an animation. You can simply play it. To play rotation or location animations at different locations ensure the animating parts of the door are parented to a not animating object, such as a static empty.

Sample structure:

- base (fixed)

  - frame (fixed)

    - wing left (animated)
    - wing right (animated)

You can align the door by moving and rotating the base object. (Indeed the frame can act as base too).